# Is there any way to find dependents of the column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm dealing with legacy database.
For example, I have table `CarTable` with definition like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CarTable] (
    [CarID] BIGINT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Status] INT NULL,
    [CarStatus] INT NULL,
);
```

I want to automatically check if any stored procedure or view references column `Status`. Is it possible?
There are many columns named `Status` in database and trivial approaches like generating database schema dump and greping won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Column dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769172/find-column-dependency)

Comment: search for: _sys.sql_expression_dependencies_

Comment: @PatrickHofman: That answer does not take Stored Procedures and views into account. Only foreign key references to columns.

Comment: @VishalGajjar: That DMV does not take non-schema-bound columns into account (views are rarely schema bound and stored procedures are never schema bound). One should use sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities instead - check out my answer below.

Comment: @Dan BOL says it does, I have not used it extensively to confirm.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx

Comment: @VishalGajjar: BOL says that column-level dependencies are only reported for schema-bound entities. 4th bullet from the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  Right click the Table (in Object Explorer) and select "View Dependencies".

Comment: It shows only dependents of table (there are few hundreds of dependents), not dependents of column.

Comment: Oops.  Didn't pick up on the reference to the column.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities and sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities to do what you want.

For example, this query gives you all objects that (directly) reference the `Status` column of the `CarTable` table:

```
 select referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name
 from 
     sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.CarTable', 'OBJECT')
 cross apply
     sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(referencing_schema_name + '.' + referencing_entity_name, 'OBJECT')
 where referenced_minor_name = 'Status'
```

Check out the [documentation of these dmv's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I have updated question - "there are many columns named `Status`".